# json.dump - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, json

I do something like this:

```
import json

data = { "id": 1 }

with open('~/Desktop/data.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f)
```

but I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...Desktop/data.json'
```

and indeed I have not created beforehand the `data.json` file in `Desktop` but I thought that this is what my code above was supposed to do.

How can I do this?

Comment: `~` is not actually a character that's part of the pathname you want to use.  The shell interprets it as a reference to your home directory, but this code isn't being processed by the shell.  You can use `os.path.expanduser()` to get the same interpretation in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can't process `~` in your file path because `~` is [bash feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html). You can get your home directory path using `os` module:

```
import os 

print(os.getenv('HOME'))
```

Answer (score 1):

to add to the previous answers:
You can use "w+" to let python create a file if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @jasonharper mentioned:

```
import json
data = { "id": 1 }
with open(os.path.expanduser("~")+'/Desktop/data.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f)
```